# transform: rotate(45deg) in to DIV inside together doesn't work truly in opera

Tags: html, css

I want to use css transform:rotate(45deg) for rotating Div 45deg, but it affects on all inside elements. I used 2 Div inside together, outer div rotates 45deg and inside DIv rotates -45deg, therefor texts in inner Div don't rotates, but it doesn't work truly in opera and its texts invert.it works in IE,Firefox and google chrome truly.
My second problem : when I want to type inside the inner DIV tag, I should change margin each time according to the size of my text to align it center of DIV tags. 
 What should I do? Thanks

css for outer DIV:

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Internet Explorer */
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
```

css for inner DIV:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(315deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
margin: 30px 115px 0 0;
```

viewing DIV and its text rotation in Opera browser:

[image]

**EDIT:**
It should be shown same this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how it _should_ look like? I'm not familiar with arabic. A fiddle would be nice as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak I added new photo that shows the true view of the text. But in the opera, texts are broken to letters and shown invert. like this: "new book" is shown same "k o o b w e n".